# GOOD tutorial(s) for learning the ASP.Net security/authentication framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Through a lot of sticking my head in the sand, reinventing the wheel and general stubbornness, I've managed to go all this time (years) avoiding learning the built-in ASP.Net support for web application authentication, users and roles. Part of the reason is that rolling my own originally seemed like less work than getting my head around all the different layers of optional abstraction provided by the ASP.Net security framework and as such I came up with a nice library that worked fine for me.

I'm now trying to go back to using as much of the built in functionality of ASP.Net (MVC2/3, not WebForms) as possible, as I've found that the more non-standard functionality you build into an application, the harder it is for other developers to pick up your code and work with it.

The web is thick with half-tutorials, badly explained articles and information that excludes important beneath-the-hood information about the ASP.Net security framework.

Are there any good tutorials that rip the lid off ASP.Net security and show you how to use it and how it all works without trying to push you through wizards and specific provider models without understanding all of the options and their pros and cons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [18 part series articles](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) from Scott Mitchell.

It's a very deep explanation of all the features that regards Authentication, Authorization and Membership providers in asp.net. I did never found a better source on this from the same author.

Comment: Wow, that looks it may be exactly what I'm looking for! Will check it out and get back to you.

Comment: Good! The articles are very well written and with many samples covering all the aspects of the membership api. I use to still read them as my only reference on that matter. Have fun!

Comment: Yep, this is what I needed. Most in-depth topics in the .Net framework, as far as I can tell, usually have at least one extremely comprehensive article or set of articles by a single author targeted at people who actually want to understand what they're doing. This fits the bill in this case I think.

Comment: Wait a second.  FormAuthentication != Membership, Profile, Role Providers which is the bulk of that article.  Knowing what response codes are set and what cookies are stored is not the same as knowing how to use the CreateUserWizard control.  Additionally my answer was not good enough because it was too old but then look at the date of this one, December 7, 2005, thats one month after .NET 2.0 was released!  There is a huge disconnect between your question and your accepted answer.  @Nathan Ridley

Comment: @jfar Not really - I used the word *framework*, implying the whole framework in which forms authentication resides.

Comment: @Nathan Ridley, so you mean the entire System.Web.Security assembly?  I'm just worried somebody will come along and think the Member,Security,Role Providers are somehow part of FormsAuthentication.  Look at MVCs sample code.  FormsAuth and Membership are totally divorced.  Its only the old WebForms controls that try and tie it all in together.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN is the best for ripping the lid off: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

Comment: I saw that article but there is a note at the top saying the content is outdated and no longer maintained, which means it may be telling me to follow outdated practices.