# Asp.NET User Authentication. MySQL,and understanding it all. New to Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GOOD tutorial(s) for learning the ASP.Net security/authentication framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240596/good-tutorials-for-learning-the-asp-net-security-authentication-framework)

So I come from a C++ background with a dabble in php sessions. I am working on a MVC4 site that will need authentication and MySQL DB backend. AKA Complete Newb to Web Dev with ASP.NET.

I am currently using EntityFramework via MySQL just fine, just need to handle sessions & Authentication now.

I have zero experience in sessions and authentication with ASP.NET. I have heard about Membership/Role providers but in reality have absolutely no clue about them. Is there a definitive guide for .NET 4 on Authentication that I can read and understand what it is and how it works or if that is even the correct classes.

From there I hear you can turn it from using mssql to use mysql by changing some configuration but a lot of what I have found is older are there any recommendations on resources for this as well?

Comment: Darxval, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow is typically for questions regarding specifics to and about code.  Generic questions about links, guides or resources diminishes the usefulness for future readers, as they may no longer be valid or be obsolete.  [Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @ErikPhilips Yeah I had a feeling, but was trying to find a place to start as I have been going around in circles.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Thanks! No idea how you found that guess my Google powers failed me today.